# php, почему сравнение двух одинаковых строк выдает false?

Tags: php

код:

```
echo gettype($_POST['login'])." ".$_POST['login'].'</br>';              
echo gettype($database[0])." ".$database[0].'</br>';              
if($_POST['login'] == $database[0] ){ echo 'sovpadayut!!!!!!!'.'</br>';}
```

результат:
string sneg2112
string sneg2112

вопрос: почему сравнение двух одинаковых строк выдает false?

Comment: Потому что строки __неодинаковы__ И выводить их надо через `var_dump`

Comment: но ведь я вставил и в файл и в форму через сtrl+v , а на счет вардамп не понял

Comment: Ну ты можешь еще полчаса доказывать всем, что строки равны. А можешь вывести каждую из них вардампом и убедиться в обратном.

Comment: Замечаешь что в одном случае string(9) а в другом string(8)? Значит в одной строке находится невидимый символ.

Comment: Будешь еще обвинять компьютер что он такой-сякой неправильно сравнивает одинаковые строки?

Comment: спасибо, понял это и удалил сразу